# Angular: 'app-tache-list' is not a known element - Error ngtsc(-998001)

Tags: angular

I'm trying to integrate the TacheListComponent into my Angular application, but I'm encountering the following error:

## # 'app-tache-list' is not a known element:

If 'app-tache-list' is an Angular component, then verify that it is included in the '@Component.imports' of this component.
If 'app-tache-list' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@Component.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.ngtsc(-998001)

Source Code:

tache-list.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-tache-list',
templateUrl: './tache-list.component.html',
styleUrls: \['./tache-list.component.css'\]
})
export class TacheListComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() { }

ngOnInit(): void {
}

}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TacheListComponent } from './components/tache/tache-list/tache-list.component';
import { TacheNewComponent } from './components/tache/tache-new/tache-new.component';

@NgModule({
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  declarations: [
    TacheListComponent,
    TacheNewComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html:

`<app-tache-list></app-tache-list>`

Actions Taken:

1/I have verified that the TacheListComponent is correctly imported in app.module.ts.
2/The selector in TacheListComponent indeed matches <app-tache-list>.

Question:

Can you help me understand why this error is occurring and how I can resolve this unknown element issue in Angular?

Comment: where is your AppCompopnent declared?